# How to append input param to string output?

Tags: java, spring, file

I have a method which takes the string as input, filters for specific key and value, returns the value as String output. I have a requirement to append input param to output string. The input is array int id. Here is the method code snippet:

```
private static String headerstomap(String headers) {
    String sHeaders = headers.replace("[", "");
    sHeaders = sHeaders.replace("]", "");
    String res = Arrays.stream(sHeaders.split(", "))
        .filter(s->s.contains("Uniquename"))
        .findFirst()
        .map(name->name.split(":")[1])
        .orElse("Not Present");
    return res;
}
```

Input is: [DomainValue:MYSQL,Oracle,SAP, Uniquename:jvmErrors_v1]

There is a rest API which takes the input param, gets the relevant data. Calls the above method to create a filename. The REST resource is:

```
public void downloadRecords(@PathVariable Long[] ids, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
```

I need the method to return: jvmErrors_v1_1

Essentially, add an underscore at the end and append the input param.

Here is the REST resource:

```
public void downloadRecords(@PathVariable Long[] ids, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        List<IDZip> iDZip = messageRepository.findbyId(ids);
        IDZip iDZip = iDZip.get(0);
        String xml = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(iDZip);
        String fileName = "id.zip";
        String xmlname = messageController.headerstomap(iDZip.getheaders());
        byte[] data = xml.getBytes();
        byte[] bytes;
        try (ByteOutputStream bout = new ByteOutputStream(); ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(bout)) {
            for (Long id : ids) {
                zout.setLevel(1);
                ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(xmlname);
                ze.setSize(data.length);
                ze.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
                zout.putNextEntry(ze);
                zout.write(data);
                zout.closeEntry();
            }
            bytes = bout.getBytes();
        }
        response.setContentType("application/zip");
        response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; " + String.format("filename=" + fileName));
        ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        FileCopyUtils.copy(bytes, outputStream);
        outputStream.close();
    }
```

There is IDZip class which holds getters and setters...

```
public String getheaders() {
        return headers;
    }

    public void setheaders(String headers) {
        this.headers = headers;
    }
```

Comment: Unrelated to your current question, but why is the input `[DomainValue:MYSQL,Oracle,SAP, Uniquename:jvmErrors_v1]` a String? I have the feeling your application/approach would benefit some libraries which will convert an incoming REST response to actual DTO objects, so you won't need to do the String conversions manually. Unless I'm missing something, and the String is coming from elsewhere as some kind of black box without any way to change it.

Comment: As for your current issue, if I understand correctly the `Long[] ids` should be appended to the `Uniquiname` result of your `headerstomap`-method for each `id`? Could you perhaps show a bit more relevant body of the `downloadRecords` method, where the `headerstomap` and `id` would come in play and you'd want to append them? (PS: Since your `headerstomap` only returns the value of the `Uniquename`, I would name that method differently, like `retrieveUniquenameFromHeaders` or something along those lines.)

Comment: @Kevin Cruijssen [DomainValue:MYSQL,Oracle,SAP, Uniquename:jvmErrors_v1] is the column value of a Record which is retrieved from MSSQL backend. Also your understanding is correct ie Long[] ids should be appended to the Uniquiname result of headerstomap-method for each id.

Comment: @Kevin Cruijssen I have updated the question with some more details.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I will give you a gift today only  if you will accept it, first debugs the process into small section system.out.println("step 1"); in each of the line then i will take it from that point

Comment: Advice on how the tackle the problem (vs. an answer) are better served by a comment. Feel free to skip the real basic questions like this; trying to advise on how to debug such jobs would be an endless, thankless task :) – welcome to stackoverflow!